# How to find total number of question, total correct answer and total incorrect?

Tags: postgresql

```
 Table-Red
"user_question_id": 1
"option_one_correct": true,
"user_option_one_correct": true,
"option_two_correct": true,
"user_option_two_correct": true,
"option_three_correct": true,
"user_option_three_correct": true,
"option_four_correct": true,
"user_option_four_correct": true,
"option_five_correct": true,
"user_option_five_correct": true,
"one_incorrect": 0,
"two_correct": 1,
"two_incorrect": 0,
"three_correct": 1,
"three_incorrect": 0,
"four_correct": 1,
"four_incorrect": 0,
"five_correct": 1,
"five_incorrect": 0,

"user_question_id": 2
"option_one_correct": true,
"user_option_one_correct": true,
"option_two_correct": true,
"user_option_two_correct": true,
"option_three_correct": false,
"user_option_three_correct": true,
"option_four_correct": false,
"user_option_four_correct": true,
"option_five_correct": true,
"user_option_five_correct": true,
"one_correct": 1,
"one_incorrect": 0,
"two_correct": 1,
"two_incorrect": 0,
"three_correct": 0,
"three_incorrect": 1,
"four_correct": 0,
"four_incorrect": 1,
"five_correct": 1,
"five_incorrect": 0,
```

**Expected Result is total result total question,total correct answer,total incorrect answer**

How to find total question and total correct and incorrect answer by query. i tried many ways but didn't find any solution

Comment: Is this postgresql structure ? This is a table ? Or json ?

Comment: @Kadet This a postgresql structure table..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that table has name `table1` and field names are case sensitive (because of apostrophes)

```sql
select 
  count(*)*5 questions, sum("one_correct"+"two_correct"+"three_correct"+"four_correct"+"five_correct") correct_answers,
sum("one_incorrect"+"two_incorrect"+"three_incorrect"+"four_incorrect"+"five_incorrect") incorrect_answers from table1
```